# JavaScript weird arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I am handling a button click in JavaScript. This below code is inside a class, by the way, I am using ReactJS library. 
Code:

```
 this.handleClick = (bipinValue)=>(event)=>{ console.log("button clicked "+bipinValue+" by this "+event.target.value)}
```

And inside render method of the same class. Code is below:

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick('bipin')} value="btn">Click me!<button>
```

Now my question I that what is this ()=>()=>{} Syntax in above code . I know only this ()=>{}, this is arrow function.

> OUTPUT: button clicked bipin by this btn.

Comment: Just a function that, when called, returns another function. Not a React thing.

Comment: Would it make more sense to you if it was written `(bipinValue => (event => { console.log("button clicked "+bipinValue+" by this "+event.target.value) }))`?

Comment: but how it is giving bipinValue if it returned before running inner returned function?

Comment: Outer function is called during DOM creation (to set inner function as a handler), inner function is called on click.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, you created a function that returns a function.

To elaborate, you created a handler with the constant value "bipin" that will be passed on every click as well (on that specific handler). `event.target.value` will be the `value` attribute of the button at the time the click occurred.

The code `this.handleClick('bipin')` creates the function:

```
(event) => {console.log("button clicked bipin by this " + event.target.value)}
```

What might explain better what is actually going on here, is to see the code without arrow functions:

```
this.handleClick = function(bipinValue) {
    return function(event) {
        console.log("button clicked "+bipinValue+" by this " + event.target.value);
    }
}
```

Nothing weird, just JavaScript